# How to include email in SAML2 response in OKTA

Tags: okta

I have never used OKTA before. I have setup an APP in OKTA to test SAML authentication. Created users in Directory. My client web application is able to login using OKTA authentication with SAML 2. However, my client web application is also expecting email in SAML2 response. How do i include email in Response from OKTA?. Currently in SAML 2 response i only see saml2:NameID

Steps i followed
1>Login to OKTA dashboard as admin
2>Goto Directory -> Profile Editor -> Select `My App` -> profile
2>Add new Attribute  as below
[image]

3> after saving attribute, click on Mappings
4> Select `Okta User to My App` tab and set the mapping as below
[image]

ISSUE

After successful authentication, the response SAML 2 from OKTA does not include `email` attribute. The only attribute i see is `NameID`

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new SAML integration, or modify an existing one, you can define custom attribute statements. These statements are inserted into the SAML assertions shared with your app.

1. In the Admin Console, go to Directory > Profile Editor, and find the
   integration you just created. Click Profile.
2. In the Attributes screen that opens, click Add Attribute.
3. Add a new attribute and click Save
4. In the Admin Console, go to Applications > Application and click the
   app name.
5. In the screen that opens, click the General tab. Then click Edit in
   the SAML Settings section.
6. In the screen that opens, click Next.
7. In the Attribute Statements (Optional) section, type in the name of
   the attribute you just created in step 3. This value does not
   populate the drop-down box automatically. For the Value, type
   "appuser", a period, and the attribute name. For example, if your
   attribute is named NewRole, the Value is appuser.NewRole.
8. When done, click Next.
9. On the Applications page, click the integration name, then click the
   Assignments tab. Click Assign, and select Assign to Groups. In the
   window, click Assign to the right of the group. You can verify these
   assignments with a SAML tracer.

More details here:
https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/How-to-define-and-configure-a-custom-SAML-attribute-statement?language=en_US